# Can we make migrating to partner sites quicker

Tags: discussion, review-queues, migration

From time to time there are questions that are very interesting, but off-topic at *stackoverflow*. Migration through voting works only with a very small set of partner sites and also seems to be a very slow process. In most cases users are better off deleting and posting to the partner site on their own.

I feel that we should prioritize migrations more. My suggestion:

- Introduce a **new migration queue**
- **Offer migration to all related sites**, also smaller ones.
- To avoid noise, **make the reviewing process strict**

There shouldn't be so many migrations votes, so the queue should be easy to handle. To avoid too many rejected migrations, the reputation threshold can be high, also only very few rejection votes could kick a question out of the queue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I added the point about more sites, because I think it makes sense. I think the consensus is: This is a bad idea, because it will lead to a high amount of rejected migrations. I wouldn't consider this an exact duplicate.

Comment: So could you edit this to focus on the speed issue - how would it work, what are the pros and cons?